# Two sounds by AudioGenerator at the same time

Tags: sound

I am learning how to generate/combine sounds using Mathematica in order to show that sounds cancel at some phases. As an exploratory example, I have

```
AudioGenerator[{"Sin", 44, 0}, 5]
```

and

```
AudioGenerator[{"Sin", 44, Pi}, 5],
```

which I want to play together to see if these cancel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a1 = AudioGenerator[{"Sin", 44, 0}, 1]
a2 = AudioGenerator[{"Sin", 44, \[Pi]}, 1]

AudioOverlay[{a1, a2}]
```

Comment: Or even `Mean[{a1, a2}]`.